# Ace web editor not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, ace-editor

When I try to load ace editor with an id other than 'editor' the editor will not show up

```
<div style="position:relative;min-height:400px;">
        <div id="editor-fr">
        </div>
</div>

{{ HTML::script('js/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js') }}

<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor-fr");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
</script>
```

In the code below, if I change the id to editor every thing will work fine. Why I not use the id editor is because I need 2 editors in my page

[image: Working]

[image: Not working]

Comment: Have you checked your CSS to verify you've set a height for the div "editor-fr"? Remember - the ACE editor will not show up without a specified height. It could be that you have #editor set with a height but not #editor-fr. Per ACE documentation, you can also use `#editor-fr { position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }`

Answer (score 17):

Set width and height of the editor like this:

```
<div id="editor-fr" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
```